# How do I determine which monitor my winform is in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I have been up and down this site and found a lot of info on the Screen class and how to count the number of monitors and such but how do I determine which montitor a form is currently in?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simpler method than using the bounds is to use the Screen.FromControl() method. This is the same functionality that Windows uses.

```
Screen.FromControl(this)
```

will return the screen object for the screen that contains most of the form that you call it from.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you:

```
private Screen FindCurrentMonitor(Form form) 
{ 
    return Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(new Rectangle( _
        form.Location, form.Size)); 
}
```

It will return the screen that has the majority of the form in it. Alternativley, you can use

```
return Windows.Forms.Screen.FromPoint(Form.Location);
```

to return the screen that has the top left corner of the form in it.

Answer (score 1):

I did notice that but I was hoping for something more elequent (from .net not from you.)
So based on your advice I did this:

```
    foreach (Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        if (screen.Bounds.Contains(this.Location))
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = screen.DeviceName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Screen object has a [Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) property you can use to find the coordinates the screen occupies, just check where the form is.