# which screen my Application is in

Tags: c#, wpf, window, screen

if the computer has more than one monitors, 
usually the app pops in the screen where the exe file was clicked.
But the exe file could be place in any screen.

So i want to know in which screen my app is located.

I checked on `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`
but could not find a way to tell which one my app is currently in.

Thanks

Comment: another [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334928/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-my-winform-is-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know what monitor a WPF window is in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465646/how-do-i-know-what-monitor-a-wpf-window-is-in)